# ORM: Sequelize: Can I use raw queries in seeders files?

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

I would like to make the following query into the seeder file:

```sql
INSERT INTO `product_attribute` (` product_id`, `attribute_value_id`)
       SELECT `p`.`product_id`,` av`.`attribute_value_id`
       FROM `product`` p`, `attribute_value`` av`;
```

Can I do `sequelize db: seed` in one of two ways:`model.findOrcreate ()`,`queryInterface.sequelize.query ()`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it in both ways.

There is a code sample in [my repository](https://github.com/leejh3224/sequelize-migrations/blob/master/seeders/20190509063314-user-post.js) using `model.create`.

And also you can always use `sequelize.query` if you want to like,

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query(
      'YOUR_QUERY_HERE'
    );
  },
```